# SQLAlchemy - reduce commits count

Tags: python, postgresql, transactions, sqlalchemy, unit-of-work

I use SQLAlchemy 0.9.8 and PostgreSQL 9.3 for a pretty heavy loaded project. However I still believe that its overhead acceptable on this stage of the project life. As far as I understand, it uses **unit of work** pattern, with implicit `begin` before first query to the DB and explicit `commit` (or `rollback`) at the end of the HTTP request processing. DB logs analyzing tool (pgbadger) shows that the most often DB query is `commit`. Also this query is one of the slowest queries. Now, I want to decrease amount of useless `commits` issued by SQLAlchemy's default workflow. Is there some other well-known patterns of using this ORM?

Comment: Are you in autocommit or are you calling Session.commit in many places. The normal workflow in SqlAlchemy is to create a session for a unit of work (i.e. a web request or task job or something similar), do all that work with that session, then when you are done you call Session.commit at the end, or rollback of it failed.

If you are getting a new session for each query you would get this type of behavior. Without some code samples or more details, that's the best I can do.

Comment: I use standard workflow (unit of work). There is only one commit at the end of request. But a lot of requests use only SELECT queries, or don't require atomicity. So, I have a lot of useless commits.

Comment: With the details you provide (not so many), just a few things come to mind: a "useless commit" as you call it such take very little time => actually you should try to look for the queries in which you are spending more time, not the most frequent. Anyhow, it is weird that the most frequent query you get is commit, even if it is a "useless commit", it should be preceded by a `select`. Actually `select` should be the most frequent query. Maybe it is a clue that something is not ok (like the `autocommit` that @MichaelRobellard  was suggesting). Hope it helps.

Comment: @lrnzcig, actually, `commit` is the most frequent query through the slowest queries. Of course, `select` is the leader in general.

Comment: Ok. But the picture still does not quite fit. If many commits are "useless commits", they should take virtually no time. I don't really know this pgbadger, is that what you are using?, anyway you should be able to tell if there are slow and fast commits.

Answer (score 0):

You can check there are anything in your session before commit:

```
session.new  # new
session.dirty  # updated
session.deleted  # deleted
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Especially if there will be many requests with only `SELECT` queries. I'm going to collect some statistics.